# Python sql dataframe data type conversion splitting into date and time columns

Tags: python, sql, pandas, datetime, time

I have a SQL File, and I upload in and read it with pandas to have its data in a data frame. I converted the column 'TIME' that has the day and time ( YEAR-MONTH-DAY HOURS:MIN:SEC).

```
    df['TIME']=pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'])
```

Then I try applying

```
    df['DAY TIME']=df['TIME'].transform (lambda x:x.time())
```

And it gave me

```
    AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'time'
```

Comment: Use `df['DAY TIME']=df['TIME'].dt.time`

Comment: It gave me :  ValueError: cannot include dtype 'M' in a buffer

Comment: Do you first use `df['TIME']=pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'])` ?

Comment: Yes I did use  df['TIME']=pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'])

Comment: Sorry, it did work after all I had a typo, thanks :)